# Completing scala promises race

Tags: scala, concurrency, atomic, race-condition, concurrent.futures

I can't seem to find anywhere whether complete and tryComplete are atomic operations on Promises in Scala. Promises are only supposed to be written to once, but if two tryCompletes happen concurrently in two different callbacks for example could something go wrong? Or are we assured that tryComplete is atomic?

Comment: Promise is completed only once; but maybe you mean, if T1 tries to complete with a computation that is long-running, then T2 tries to complete (perhaps testing isComplete) with a quick value, does T2 win?

Comment: Apparently, T2. So T1 does not "lock" the promise when it enters tryComplete. Not sure if that is your question, however.

Comment: @som-snytt The point you made is extra information which is definitely interesting. I just wanted to make sure if T1 and T2 run tryComplete at the exact same time, that only one of them actually succeeds and the other fails and nothing strange happens. I don't know how to test it because obviously I can't time something like that.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#promises  The scaladoc is surprisingly thin.

Comment: Also my previous speculation was meaningless: `Try { compute }` is eager and completes before handed to `tryComplete`. It's not as compelling to say the same thing about completeWith: you don't expect the first completeWith to get its shot before the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a quick note that `success(...)` is equivalent to calling `complete(Success(...))` and `tryComplete(...)` is equivalent to `complete(...).isCompleted`.

In the docs it says

> As mentioned before, promises have single-assignment semantics. As such, they can be completed only once. Calling success on a promise that has already been completed (or failed) will throw an IllegalStateException.

A promise can only complete once. Digging into the source code, `DefaultPromise` extends `AtomicReference` (ie. thread safe) and so all writes are atomic. This means that if you have two threads completing a promise, only one of them can ever succeed and it'll be whichever did so first. The other will throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Here's a small example of what happens when you try and complete a promise twice.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hTYBqVywSQCl8bFSgQI0Sg

Though apparently it seems one can circumvent the immutability of a `Future` by doing a bunch of weird casting acrobatics.

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/defaultpromise-violates-encapsulation/3440

One should probably avoid that.